# How to set shared memory in Docker Compose configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do you specify [shared memory size](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#shm_size) in a Docker Compose configuration file?

I have an application that requires at least 2gb of shared memory, which I'd normally specify during `docker run` using the `--shm-size 2g` option.

According to the Docker Compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-23), support for `shm-size` was added in version 2.3. However, if I run `docker-compose` with the trivial configuration:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app_test:
    build:
      context: .
      shm_size: '2gb'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
```

it fails with the error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.test.yml' is invalid because:
services.app_test.build contains unsupported option: 'shm_size'
```

I'm using docker-compose version 1.24.1, which should be the [most recent release](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) that supports all modern file versions, including support for `shm-size`. Why is it giving me this error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use version "3.5"
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#shm_size

Comment: You have `shm_size:` indented so it's under `build:`.  You probably don't mean that (though it should be valid; it just means something different than you want, modifying a `docker build` rather than a `docker run` step).